# understanding anonymous function works in javascript code

Tags: javascript, anonymous-function, lexical-scope

I am a bit perplexed when i saw a piece of code and trying to understand why calling it anonymous keeps the value of total and not otherwise.

```js
var adder = function (total) {
// the following function is returned 
// and assigned to adder

    var inner_function = function (summand) {
        total += summand;
        alert(total);
    }

    return inner_function;

}(0) // <- we call the annonymous function 
//    and assign the returned function to adder
adder(2); // -> 2
adder(3); // -> 5
```

What I don't understand is if i don't invoke anonymous function, it doesn't keep the value of total. why? without (0) if i am calling adder(2) shouldn't it behave like the first call where it keeps the value of total and then assign internal_function to variable adder?

It says in the blog that 
"And when you call adder, that is the inner_function, it has access to total due to Lexical Scoping, even though the function that had the total. total itself was declared in the scope of a function that has returned a long time ago."
http://pierrespring.com/2010/05/11/function-scope-and-lexical-scoping/

just trying to understand how anonymous works in this case

Comment: The value of total isn't kept because if you don't invoke the anonymous function no value is set...total in that case would be undefined.

Comment: @Andreas I don't think this is a duplicate but the info there will help answer the question.

Comment: what i am trying to understand when i don't call anonymous function and instead call adder(2), won't it be passed as total?

Comment: The function that takes `total` is called with the `(0)`, not the `inner_function`. Both are not completely anonymous by the way (which can e.g. be seen by `let x = () => 0, y = x; console.log(y.name);`) but that's a technical detail i suppose. And i also think this is a duplicate, this topic is confusing, yes, but has been asked very very often already.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't invoke the function, there is no `total` yet. Your `adder` would refer to the outer function. `adder(2)` would bind `total` to `2` and return the inner function (which you ignore). `adder(3)` would bind `total` to `3` and return another inner function (which you also ignore).

Specifically:

```
var adder = function (total) {
    var inner_function = function (summand) {
        total += summand;
        alert(total);
    }

    return inner_function;    
};
```

is like

```
function adder(total) {
    var inner_function = function (summand) {
        total += summand;
        alert(total);
    }

    return inner_function;
}
```

Then

```
adder(2)  // returns `inner_function`
```

has no visible effect if you don't save its return value and invoke that.

Comment: It would be more appropriate to call it `makeAdder` then

Answer (score 1):

```js
var adder = function (total) {
// the following function is returned 
// and assigned to adder

    var inner_function = function (summand) {
        total += summand;
        alert(total);
    }

    return inner_function;

}(0) // <- we call the annonymous function 
//    and assign the returned function to adder
adder(2); // -> 2
adder(3); // -> 5
```

When you call the function (`0`) at the end of the line, you are actually running the outer function (the one that accepts `total`) and it returns the inner_function. So after the call `adder` contains the `inner_function`.
Now, when you ommit calling the function, the adder is actually the outer_function, so calling it like `adder(2)` returns not the value, but rather the `inner_function`. Simple example:

```js
var adder = function (total) {
// the following function is returned 
// and assigned to adder

    var inner_function = function (summand) {
        total += summand;
        console.log(total);
    }

    return inner_function;

}
adder(5)(2); // -> 7
```

Comment: when we call the anonymous, how is it able to keep the value total and adder(2) and adder(3) are adding up? but if i don't i have to call the external and internal function to add the values?

Comment: Check out the link from the comment of Andreas (about duplicate question) answers exactly your questions. :)